# Not be able to run Node-red server?

Tags: node.js, registry, node-red

I am not able to start my Node-red server, I even removed nodejs and all npm folders including node-red but it didn't help. When I remove all foreach loops in the Registry.js file then the server doesn't crash but it keeps loading the nodes but you can't work in it.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of error messages, they are impossible to search for and really hard to read. Edit the question to include the actual text and use the tool bar format it correctly

Comment: Also inlcude information about how you installed Node-RED and what you did/changed before it failed to start (e.g. what nodes you have recently installed)